# lxml event parsing big file to extract only some data

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

I've seen quite a few questions here about lxml parsing and while they're all immensely useful, some problems are specific to the structure of the file being parsed.

In my case I have an xml which looks like this:

```
<documents>
    <document>
        <id>123456</id>
        <element name="name">
            <value><![CDATA[john doe]]></value>
        </element>
        <element name="address">
            <value><![CDATA[no name street]]></value>
        </element>
    </document>
</documents>
```

The actual xml has a lot more elements but this is just to exemplify.
My final purpose will be to extract some of this information into a csv so that I have the following result:

```
id, name, address
123456,john doe,no name street
```

However my problem is parsing the file to get the values inside the "value" elements depending on a condition (if the parent "element" has a specific attribute).

Because the real file I'll be parsing is around 8gb I figured it would be best to make use of lxml's iterparse to avoid storing a big tree in memory.

This is the code I have now, I'm kind of stuck in the end when trying to check the text from the next element if "element"s attribute "name" is equal to the values specified in the list "attributes":

```
from lxml import etree

attributes = ("name", "address")
context = etree.iterparse("test.xml", tag="document")

for event, element in context:
    for child in element:
        if child.attrib.get("name") in attributes:
            print child.getnext().text
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really "next", rather descendant, so you can just make another loop, I think. If `value` is always the only child element, you can do:

```
from lxml import etree

attributes = ("name", "address")
context = etree.iterparse("test.xml", tag="document")

for event, element in context:
    for child in element:
        if child.attrib.get("name") in attributes:
            print next(c for c in child).text
    element.clear() # clear the subtree from the memory
```

Otherwise you can make a full `for` loop inside the if going somewhat like

```
if child.attrib.get("name") in attributes:
    for subchild in child:
        if subchild.tag == 'value':
            print subchild.text
```